"tough thought": is this combination nonsensical?
From an FB publication:

English can be weird. But it can be understood through tough thorough thought, though.

I suspect that, even if thoughts can poetically be 'tough' sometimes, the toughness of thought is no indication of how quickly understanding can be arrived at. One can think 'hard' but not 'tough'. I don't believe they are synonymous in this context, are they?

Don't worry too much about the meaning. It's obviously a contrived sentence, designed to use five very similar English words all together.

The sentence is a joke about how the letters "-ough" can have many pronunciations. Arguably, it could be improved by a comma after "tough."

Is the combination nonsensical?  Not pure nonsense. You can guess at what it might mean.
However it would be extremely unusual for someone to say:
"That's a tough thought!"
There are corner cases for almost anything. In some word games, or creative conversation, the phrase could appear.
But it is not idiomatic.
Rather, the text was meant to playfully show how "ough" is pronounced in multiple ways.
through tough thorough thought though

Many native speakers (readers, really) will find such collections of words ugly on the page.
